# problema conexion postgresql php con objetos

Tags: php, postgresql

hola estoy teniendo problemas para conectarme a la BD con postgres mediante PHP
adjunto el código php de la clase conexión, cuando creo un objeto conexiones y llamo el al método conectar este no me retorna nada, hay alguna forma de ver el error como mysql_error??

```
    class Conexiones
    { /*ATRIBUTOS*/
      private $servidor='localhost';
      private $bd='baseclientes';
      private $user='postgres';
      private $password='hom';
      private $postgres= 0;

      /** METODOS */
      public function conectar ()
      {
       $pgConnectionString = "host='$this->servidor' port=5432 dbname='$this->bd' user='$this->user' password='$this->password'";

if ($this->postgres= pg_connect($pgConnectionString))
     {return 0;}// todo ok
else {return 1;}
} /* FIN METODO CONEXION*/

} /*FIN CLASE CONEXIONES*/
```

pd: nunca trabajé con postgres es probable que le este errando en algún lado, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente modificar un poco la clase que ya tiene de esta manera te puede indicar al instanciar la clase si la conexión se hizo, adicionalmente por temas prácticos no recomiendo que dentro de una clase para hacer una conexión a base de datos contenga las credenciales.

```
<?php

class Conexiones
{

    private $connexion = NULL;

    public function _construct ($host, $dbname, $username, $password)
    {
        $conn_string = "host=$this->servidor port=5432 dbname=$this->db user=$this->user password=$this->password";
        $this->connexion = pg_connect($conn_string) or die('Conexión fallida');
        return $this->connexion;

    }
}


$credentials = [
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'dbname' => 'baseclientes',
    'username' => 'postgres',
    'password' => 'hom'
];

$pgconn = new Conexiones($credentials['host'], $credentials['dbname'], $credentials['username'], $credentials['password']);
```

Existe una mejor documentación en el sitio oficial de [PHP - función pg_connect](http://php.net/manual/es/function.pg-connect.php)

Comment: probé este codigo pero no me dice me muestra  ni error ni conexion realizada

Comment: @fer que versión de php utiliza y en que sistema operativo?, muy posiblemente le este faltando instalar el paquete php-pgsql

Comment: la version de php que usa es 5.6 desconozco si está instalado ese paquete pero probe otro código y me anduvo, pude traer mostrar datos de la bd en la pagina

Comment: @fer excelente, sería genial que compartiera la solución ...